# How to find out version of ghc that corresponds to snapshot without causing download of ghc

Tags: haskell-stack

Need a way to determine the ghc version associated with a given snapshot without having to download ghc.

I could run this command to get the information, but unfortunately, it first downloads the ghc before printing out the version:

`stack query compiler wanted`

I need this because I am optimising a CI build and having a way to obtain the ghc version allows me to use that as a key to retrieve the appropriate build cache.  The fact that trying to query this information triggers a download undermines any optimisation I attempt.

Comment: Yeah, some of the output of `stack query` depends on having GHC installed. It would be great to modify stack to avoid this when the user asks for a subset that does not depend on the compiler.  For now a hacky way to do it would be `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/lts-haskell/master/...` (or `stackage-nightly`), and then parse out `system-info.core-packages.ghc`

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but one can parse the stdout or stderr of

```
stack --resolver SNAPSHOT --no-install-ghc query
```

or `stack --resolver SNAPSHOT --no-install-ghc path --compiler-exe`.

Or here is a small program using [pantry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pantry) to get the info:

```
import Pantry

main :: IO ()
main = do
  rsnap <-
    runPantryApp $ do
    let rurl = defaultSnapshotLocation (LTS 18 0)
    url <- completeSnapshotLocation rurl
    loadSnapshot url
  print $ rsCompiler rsnap
```

Answer (score -1):

@mgsloan gave me enough information to put together a solution, which can be found here:

https://github.com/haskell-works/hw-dsv/blob/master/scripts/ghc-version

Comment: I believe this only works with stack version 1.

I believe pantry downloads snapshot metadata directly from the yaml files in https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/.